# C# Xamarin Two types which are the same, not seen as the same

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, types

Im getting myself in a muddle so any pointers in the right direction would be greatly received.

I have a Mobile App that im writing using Xamarin Forms.

In the main app I have a 'Connected Service' - which was declared using a WebService WSDL. Its created its own types which is fine.

As the work to connect to the webservice and retrieve data is actually done on the platform dependent project, the same types in the 'parent' project, also exist in the platform dependent projects. For example, the 'parent' has a type/class of 'StationBoardWithDetails1' which has numerous other custom types/classes underneath it.

When the platform dependent project attempts to return 'StationBoardWithDetails1' it comes back as a 'Droid.NameSpace.StationBoardWithDetails1', so when i try to use that in the 'parent' project view model, it complains it doesnt know what a 'Droid.NameSpace.StationBoardWithDetails1' is, but it does know what its own NameSpace.StationBoardWithDetails1 is. I cant seem to convert the two 'StationBoardWithDetails1' across the projects without the compiler complaining.

Error   CS0039  Cannot convert type '.Droid.DroidNRE.StationBoardWithDetails1' to '.NRE.StationBoardWithDetails1' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion    .Android\SoapService.cs Line 95

Any Pointers?

Comment: First, consider posting the relevant code.  It sounds like you have the same class definition in two different classes - which as far as C# is concerned means they are two completely different classes.  Is there a reason the webservice work is being done in the platform project?  If you moved it to the shared Forms project you would not have this problem.  Alternately, you can create a separate project containing the duplicated class, and have both shared and platform projects reference that common project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It features here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/asmx and talks about having to use a proxy for an async lookup to keep the app responsive. I hadnt considered using an alternative project containing the class - i will look into that thanks. I would post the code but the WSDL reference is >3000 lines alone.

Comment: I have not done this in several years, but to the best of my recollection I was able to have the services live in the shared project.

Comment: The code generated on the Shared Project goes in as a Connected Service, whereas in the droid project it goes in as a webservice and allows events to be registered from it - i had to hunt to find the microsoft docs article above, which says the only way is to use the platform project as a dependency #confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your Android project can (and should) access the "generated" classes that are in the shared project.

- Remove the copy of classes from the Android project.
- Declare the generated classes "public".
- Where the classes are needed, add a "using" statement referring to the namespace containing the generated classes.

That might be all you need to do. If not, other suggestions follow.

---

"use .. as a dependency":

**Remove** any WebService code you put in shared project. Then from shared project, when you need access, you use a [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/), to invoke the android code.

---

Sounds like you need `Types` that are not in the Droid namespace. Use **partial classes**.

In shared project:

```cs
namespace NRE {
    public partial class StationBoardWithDetails
    {
        // Members that DON'T depend on Android namespaces.
    }
}
```

If these classes need any Android-specific code:

In Android project:

```cs
namespace NRE {
    public partial class StationBoardWithDetails
    {
        // Members that DO depend on Android namespaces.
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT: Even though the second code snippet is in your Android project, *you still use the shared namespace*.

---

If the above isn't the solution, then **add to question** enough code to understand how/why `Droid.NameSpace.StationBoardWithDetails1` is being generated from the WebService call.

Bottom line is that the goal is to instead generate `NRE.StationBoardWithDetails1`.